# Spring Data JPA many to many save

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring mvc + hibernate + spring data jpa.

I have a many to many relationship between Person and SecurityRole. I want to add a new person using spring data jpa save method. When I try to save I am getting the following error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/hub] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into roles (RLE_ROLE, RLE_ID) values (?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1039)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3597)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3529)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1990)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2415)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1976)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1449)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2411)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2874)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:76)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:521)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.motodoc.hub.service.SecurityUserServiceImpl.addNewUser(SecurityUserServiceImpl.java:64)
    at com.motodoc.hub.controller.UserController.save(UserController.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
```

It seems like the save method is trying to add a new SecurityRole and since a SecurityRole already exists with the same primary key hence the error.

So my question is how do I save a new person, when given a SecurityRole which already exists in the database, it just updates only the Person and the mapping table ignoring the SecurityRole?

Your help will be much appreciated.

All the relevant code below...

Person entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="persons")
public class Person implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @Column(name="PRS_ID")
    private int id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="PRS_USERNAME")
    private String username;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="PRS_PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="PRS_FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="PRS_MIDDLE_NAME")
    private String middleName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="PRS_LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLES", joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "USR_PRS_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "RLE_ID") })
    private Set<SecurityRole> roles;

    @Transient
    private final String PERMISSION_PREFIX = "ROLE_PERM_";

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Set<GrantedAuthorityImpl> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthorityImpl>();
        for (SecurityRole role : roles) {
            for (SecurityPermission permission : role.getPermissions()) {
                GrantedAuthorityImpl authority = new GrantedAuthorityImpl(PERMISSION_PREFIX + permission.getPermission());
                authorities.add(authority);
            }
        }
        return authorities;
    }
```

SecurityRole class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class SecurityRole implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="RLE_ID")
    private int id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="RLE_ROLE")
    private String role;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "ROLE_PERMISSIONS", joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "RLE_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "PRM_ID") })
    private Set<SecurityPermission> permissions;
}
```

Service class

```
public class SecurityUserServiceImpl implements ISecurityUserService {

    @Autowired
    private IPersonDao personDao;

    @Autowired
    private IRoleDao roleDao;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;

    @Override
    public void addNewUser(AddUserForm addUserForm) {

        Person newPerson = addUserForm.getPerson();

        //encode password
        String encodedPassword = encoder.encode(newPerson.getPassword());

        //set the encoded password as the password
        newPerson.setPassword(encodedPassword);

        Set<SecurityRole> securityRoles = new HashSet<SecurityRole>();

        //get Role
        securityRoles.add(roleDao.findById(addUserForm.getRoleId()));

        newPerson.setRoles(securityRoles);

        //now save
        personDao.save(newPerson);
    }
}
```

IPersonDao interface:

```
public interface IPersonDao extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Person> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Person save(Person person);

}
```

IRoleDao interface:

```
public interface IRoleDao extends JpaRepository<SecurityRole, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<SecurityRole> {

    public List<SecurityRole> findAll();

    public SecurityRole findById(int id);

}
```

Persistence.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="hibernatePersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        </properties>
        <!-- <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>  -->
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: You have not added any strategy for generating the ID values. Try adding this to the ID fields in both entities: @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

Comment: I just added as you suggested but now I'm getting     org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.motodoc.hub.domain.SecurityRole error

Comment: As you note in the title, Person <> Role is a many-to-many but you have mapped it using '@OneToMany'. You should change this to @ManyToMany

Comment: Nice spot ... yes, that did the trick. Thanks

Comment: @Zahanghir, please update this post with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like OP pointed out in his comment, his problem was that he used @OneToMany instead of @ManyToMany.

When I've got a similar exception, my problem was that I didn't intend to persist the member with the @ManyToMany annotation, but I used cascade = CascadeType.ALL, which means it will try to persist it. Also, I didn't have a generation strategy for the field's ID. I have removed the cascade attribute from the ManyToMany annotation and it solved my problem.